# How to disable a button after clicking it in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to disable a button click if its already clicked once.

I have a car marketplace where dealers can upload cars. The problem is dealers feeds in duplicate listings, which I want to restrict..

Cheers

Comment: what plugin do you use for client? can you show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the ([jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)) plugin. It makes working with cookies very simple.

check if cookie exist or not when click, however first time it will not exist so create a cookie.

next time it will present, so disable the button.

```
$(document).click(function(e)){
   $('button').click(function){
    if($.cookie('the_cookie') == null){
        //do your thing
        $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value',{ expires: 1 });
    }else if($.cookie('the_cookie') != null){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("button").attr("disabled", true);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: THanks Chidambara,

Comment: if its useful means please can u upvote... if its the correct answer means can u mark as correct answer..